# Division encoding in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, css, ms-access

I have an encoding problem when populating a div with html content for another php page. Here’s the code for getting the data from the other page into the div..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function get1() {
$.post('reportlookupdetail.php', 
$('form[name="reportform"]').serialize(), 
function (output) {
$('#info').html(output).show();
});
}
</script>
```

and the div code is

```
<div id="info"></div>
```

The reportlookupdetail.php pulls data from an MS Access 2010 database. When the file is opened by itself, everything is displayed fine.  But when the function opens it in a div, I get a replacement characters sprinkled about  in the form of a small box in IE and a black diamond with a question mark in Chrome and Fire Fox.  I’ve tried,

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

on the first, second, then both pages, tried modifying the JavaScript like

```
$('#info').html(output).show('text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

and a ccs as

```
<style type="text/css">
div {
@charset "UTF-8";
}
</style>
```

But nothing seems to work. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Access should use Unicode by default (unless it's older than 2000).  It looks like jQuery has another method text().  Test out  $('#info').text(output).show();

Answer (score 0):

You cannot partial-encode character sets within a page.

The problem is likely that the data that is in your database is not in UTF-8 format in the first place. You need to get the page encoding to match the data (likely it's in [Windows 1251](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251)).

I suggest fixing your data if you can and setting it to UTF-8 and declaring UTF-8 in for page  or you'll kick yourself later.